# Testing Spring RESTful services through JMETER. How to give multiple dynamic input for XML data?

Tags: spring, rest, jmeter

```
@RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.POST, value="/employeeXML")
public ModelAndView addEmployeePostXMl(@RequestBody String body) {
    Source source = new StreamSource(new StringReader(body));
    Employee e = (Employee) jaxb2Mashaller.unmarshal(source);
    employeeDS.add(e);
    List<Employee> employees = employeeDS.getAll();
    EmployeeList list = new EmployeeList(employees);
    return new ModelAndView(XML_VIEW_NAME, "employees", list);
}
```

I am able to test it for single POST body ie

```
<employee>
   <id>3</id>
   <name>guest3</name>
   <email>guest3@ibm.com</email>
</employee>.
```

But how to check it for multiple DYNAMIC values like CSV files.If i am using csv file with data :

```
3   aFFaFD       xfchghcxh
4   dsfgsdF      cxhchcxht
5   asFDdsF      chcxhcg
6   sdFsF        cxhxhcgh
7   SDFsF        cghcxhcg
8   gfzsgzd      cxghchc
9   hgfxhfx      cghchgc
10  fghxf        ghcxhxc
11  fhgfxh       cghchcc
12  ghcxxh       cxhcghch
13  chgxgcvx     cghchcxgch
14  hgxfhxch     cxhgxchcg
15  ghcxhcx      vmcvmnvbm
16  cghch        bnmvmbh
17  cxghcxhcx    mvbhgn
18  cxghcxh      mnmcghmh
19  cxghcxhxch   mnvmvmcv
20  xcghchcx     mvcmvmv
```

it gives unmarshalling exception because the post body should be in XML format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use [JMeterRestSampler](https://github.com/smartrics/JMeterRestSampler) - custom jmeter sampler for testing REST services:

- [RestSampler project](https://github.com/smartrics/JMeterRestSampler)
- [JMeter to test robustness of system exposing REST APIs](http://smartrics.blogspot.com/2009/04/jmeter-to-test-robustness-of-system.html)

You can use it along with the following schema:

```
Thread Group
    . . .
    While Controller
    Condition: ${__javaScript("${email}"!="<EOF>",)} // until the EOF
        CSV Data Set Config
        Filename: [path to your file with test-data]
        Variable Names: id,name,email
        REST Sampler
```

```
            <employee>
                <id>${id}</id>
                <name>${name}</name>
                <email>${email}</email>
            </employee>
```

Answer (score 1):

http://www.mightythor.net/jmeter.html

can be used to run RESTfull services from JMeter.

Comment: Does it specifically address the problem the OP is having though?